# nodejs webapp goes into scavenger gc loop

Tags: node.js, memory

I have a web app written in nodejs. It runs fine without any issues or noticable memory leak for 5-10 minutes then all of a sudden it goes into a scavenger operation loop, freezing for some time and eventually exiting with heap error. It starts logging these at the end with `--trace_gc` flag

```
[84424:0x104063000]   488154 ms: Scavenge 114.0 (179.9) -> 100.0 (179.9) MB, 15.6 / 10.7 ms  (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) allocation failure
[84424:0x104063000]   488313 ms: Scavenge 115.2 (180.1) -> 100.1 (180.1) MB, 27.2 / 20.8 ms  (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) allocation failure
[84424:0x104063000]   488478 ms: Scavenge 116.3 (180.3) -> 100.3 (180.3) MB, 26.8 / 22.8 ms  (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) allocation failure
[84424:0x104063000]   488641 ms: Scavenge 116.7 (180.7) -> 100.7 (180.7) MB, 27.2 / 23.4 ms  (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) allocation failure
[84424:0x104063000]   488805 ms: Scavenge 116.7 (180.7) -> 100.7 (180.7) MB, 27.8 / 23.3 ms  (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) allocation failure
[84424:0x104063000]   488972 ms: Scavenge 117.2 (181.3) -> 101.3 (181.3) MB, 26.2 / 22.3 ms  (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) allocation failure
[84424:0x104063000]   489135 ms: Scavenge 117.2 (181.3) -> 101.3 (181.3) MB, 27.7 / 23.6 ms  (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) allocation failure
[84424:0x104063000]   489297 ms: Scavenge 118.1 (182.2) -> 102.2 (182.2) MB, 27.9 / 23.5 ms  (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) allocation failure
[84424:0x104063000]   489465 ms: Scavenge 118.1 (182.2) -> 102.1 (182.2) MB, 25.0 / 20.8 ms  (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) allocation failure
[84424:0x104063000]   489632 ms: Scavenge 118.1 (182.2) -> 102.2 (182.2) MB, 27.0 / 23.3 ms  (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) allocation failure
[84424:0x104063000]   489790 ms: Scavenge 119.4 (183.5) -> 103.4 (183.5) MB, 24.9 / 20.8 ms  (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) allocation failure
[84424:0x104063000]   489956 ms: Scavenge 119.4 (183.5) -> 103.5 (183.5) MB, 27.4 / 23.5 ms  (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) allocation failure
[84424:0x104063000]   490134 ms: Scavenge 119.4 (183.5) -> 103.5 (183.5) MB, 30.1 / 23.7 ms  (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) allocation failure
[84424:0x104063000]   490301 ms: Scavenge 119.4 (183.5) -> 103.4 (183.5) MB, 28.3 / 23.3 ms  (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) allocation failure
[84424:0x104063000]   490465 ms: Scavenge 119.4 (183.5) -> 103.5 (183.5) MB, 23.8 / 20.1 ms  (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) allocation failure
[84424:0x104063000]   490634 ms: Scavenge 121.4 (185.5) -> 105.4 (185.5) MB, 26.6 / 22.2 ms  
...
[84424:0x104063000]   492441 ms: Scavenge 124.3 (188.4) -> 108.4 (188.4) MB, 27.9 / 23.3 ms  (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) allocation failure
[84424:0x104063000]   492606 ms: Scavenge 124.3 (188.4) -> 108.4 (188.4) MB, 27.2 / 23.5 ms  
...
[84424:0x104063000]   494834 ms: Scavenge 128.8 (192.8) -> 112.8 (192.8) MB, 26.8 / 22.9 ms  (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) allocation failure
[84424:0x104063000]   494996 ms: Scavenge 128.8 (192.8) -> 112.8 (192.8) MB, 29.5 / 25.4 ms  (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) allocation failure
[84424:0x104063000]   495165 ms: Scavenge 128.8 (192.8) -> 112.8 (192.8) MB, 27.4 / 23.4 ms  (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) allocation failure
...
[84424:0x104063000]   507290 ms: Mark-sweep 148.3 (224.4) -> 105.0 (176.8) MB, 24.3 / 0.6 ms  (+ 17.3 ms in 65 steps since start of marking, biggest step 11.6 ms, walltime since start of marking 102 ms) (average mu = 0.998, current mu = 0.998) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
...
[84424:0x104063000]   507612 ms: Scavenge 118.6 (176.8) -> 102.7 (176.8) MB, 26.8 / 22.9 ms  (average mu = 0.998, current mu = 0.998) allocation failure
```

the memory goes high and then it crashes.

What are the potential reasons for this behavior? I understand scavenge is for moving objects from new space to old space, but old space does not seem to be full when it starts. Is there something else it indicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior happens if there is an infinite loop of promises. No stack overflow error, no other message, it just fills up the memory and eventually goes into scavenge loop then heap out of space error and crash.